# Adding new property to Eloquent Collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-collection

Trying to add new property to existing collection and access that.

What I need is something like:

```
$text = Text::find(1);  //Text model has properties- id,title,body,timestamps
$text->user = $user;
```

And access the user via, `$text->user`.

Exploring on documentation and SO, I found `put`, `prepend`, `setAttribute` methods to do that.

```
$collection = collect();
$collection->put('a',1);
$collection->put('c',2);
echo $collection->c; //Error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$c
```

Again,

```
$collection = collect();
$collection->prepend(1,'t');
echo $collection->t = 5; //Error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$t
```

And

```
$collection = collect();
$collection->setAttribute('c',99); // Error: undefined method setAttribute
echo $collection->c;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you mix here Eloquent collection with Support collection. Also notice when you are using:

```
$text = Text::find(1);  //Text model has properties- id,title,body,timestamps
$text->user = $user;
```

you don't have here any collection but only single object.

But let's look at:

```
$collection = collect();
$collection->put('a',1);
echo $collection->c; //Error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$c
```

You are taking `c` and you don't have such element. What you should do is taking element that is at `a` key like this:

```
echo $collection->get('a');
```

or alternatively using array access like this:

```
echo $collection['a'];
```

Also notice there is no `setAttribute` method on Collection. There is `setAttribute` method on Eloquent model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, laravel documentation tells, query like 'all' or 'get' returns instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. So shouldn't be `setAttribute` method available? And I updated the example of "using put method".

Comment: No, setAttribute is available for single model, and you don't use here anywhere `get` or `all` to get models. If you want to have collection of models you could use: `$text = Text::where('id', 1)->get();` and now you have first model in `$text[0]` but obviously when you are looking by id it does not make any sense to have collection of results because you have only single element with this id.

Comment: Got the point I was missing. Accepting your answer. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: ok. When you use Laravel validation, the result of `$validated = $validator->safe()` is a collection, on which we can then use collection methods such as `only()`. And you can access the properties like an object: `$validated->some_property`
How do I create such a collection, given an associative array to start?