# Laravel create collection with named properties from scratch

Tags: laravel, collections

My question is similar to this question [Adding new property to Eloquent Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364421/adding-new-property-to-eloquent-collection), but I need some further explanation.

In many occasions it would be really useful to be able to construct your own collections and use Laravel collection methods. The docs only explain how to make a simple collection of nameless items (a 1 dimensional data set), but I'm interested in 2 dimensional data sets.

For example when you use Laravel validator, it takes your named array of inputs and spits out a `Illuminate\Support\ValidatedInput` object, which is a collection. Then you can access your properties as properties in any object and also use collection methods such as `only()` or `except()`.

```
$safe = $request->safe(); //returns a Illuminate\Support\ValidatedInput collection
//$safe = $request->validate(); //returns an associative array

echo $safe->my_prop;
Model::create( $safe->only(['prop1', 'prop2']) );
```

My objective is to transform an associative array such as:

```
$a = [
  'prop1' => 'val1',
  'prop2' => 3656,
  'prop3' => ['stuff', 'more']
];
```

Into a collection that can be used like the `Illuminate\Support\ValidatedInput` object.

PS I'm currently using arrays and array functions (like  `array_intersect_key()` as a substitute to `->only()`), but would rather use collections.

---

Using

```
$c = collect( $a );
```

you cannot access the properties of $c like `$c->prop`, you still need to use `$c['prop']`. Which is confusing, given that many objects in laravel are both objects (which allow `$object->property`) AND collections.

Comment: You can convert arrays to collections like: `$collection = collect($array);`. But maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly.

Comment: Does this solve the problem? https://gist.github.com/brunogaspar/154fb2f99a7f83003ef35fd4b5655935

Comment: @geertjanknapen I tried to make my issue clearer. See the post

Comment: @GertB. That's very cool! I could have used it in other occasions. Thank you